# Problem with \pgfmathparse and font style of array elements

Tags: fonts, arrays, pgfmath

There are probably other ways to do that, but I was happy I've found this code working just fine for my needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{grpcnt}
\def\groups{grp1, grp2, grp3}
\def\keyvals{{ {"key 00/val 00, key 01/val 01"}, {"key 10/val 10, key 11/val 11, key 12/val 12"}, {"key 20/val 20"} }}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{grpcnt}{0}
\foreach \grp in \groups {
    \section*{\grp}
    \pgfmathparse{\keyvals[\thegrpcnt]}
    \foreach \key/\val in \pgfmathresult
    {
        \textbf{\key}: \val \\[1ex]
    }
    \addtocounter{grpcnt}{1}
}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have is if I try to store any font styling in the 2nd array, say an `\emph{}` on the first value 00:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{grpcnt}
\def\groups{grp1, grp2, grp3}
\def\keyvals{{ {"key 00/val \emph{00}, key 01/val 01"}, {"key 10/val 10, key 11/val 11, key 12/val 12"}, {"key 20/val 20"} }}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{grpcnt}{0}
\foreach \grp in \groups {
    \section*{\grp}
    \pgfmathparse{\keyvals[\thegrpcnt]}
    \foreach \key/\val in \pgfmathresult
    {
        \textbf{\key}: \val \\[1ex]
    }
    \addtocounter{grpcnt}{1}
}
\end{document}
```

Which will break compilation. I found out that some other types of commands are seen and interpreted correctly (e.g., some special characters like `\AE` work just fine), but any font syling command I've tried (`\large`, `\textbf{}`, `\itshape`, etc.) have failed. Any idea why and/or how I could store some font styling in the 2nd array? Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. This is a great first question. I don't use this feature but the problem is that TeX expects the values to be well, mathematical values *not* text. If you want to do something similar with text, I think you would be better off using something designed to deal with it.

Comment: As @cfr says, welcome to TeX.SX! Also, a tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @cfr: well, I will certainly try to find another way...

Comment: from the names of your macros I would recommend switching to a key value system such as pgfkeys. ther yiu can store or manipulate things much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgfmathparse` performs `\edef` and commands such as `\emph` don't survive it.

You get what you need by preceding such commands with `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{grpcnt}
\def\groups{grp1, grp2, grp3}
\def\keyvals{{ {"key 00/val \noexpand\emph{00}, key 01/val 01"},
  {"key 10/val 10, key 11/val 11, key 12/val 12"}, {"key 20/val 20"} }}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{grpcnt}{0}

\foreach \grp in \groups {%
    \section*{\grp}
    \pgfmathparse{\keyvals[\thegrpcnt]}
    \foreach \key/\val in \pgfmathresult
    {%
      \textbf{\key}: \val \\[1ex]
    }%
    \addtocounter{grpcnt}{1}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What are the “dangerous” commands? It's not easy to tell. But font changing commands surely are, as well as some other text producing ones.

---

A completely different implementation that doesn't require any protection; the input of groups is changed, but I believe that a group and its corresponding list should be input together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,indentfirst}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definegroup}{mm}
 {
  \shrodi_define_group:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\processgroups}{ }
 {
  \shrodi_process_groups:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_shrodi_groups_seq
\cs_new:Npn \__shrodi_make_name:n #1
 {
  g_shrodi_\tl_to_str:n{#1}_clist
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shrodi_define_group:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_shrodi_groups_seq { #1 }
  \clist_new:c { \__shrodi_make_name:n { #1 } }
  \clist_gset:cn { \__shrodi_make_name:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shrodi_process_groups:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_shrodi_groups_seq
   {
    \section* { ##1 }
    \clist_map_inline:cn { \__shrodi_make_name:n { ##1 } }
     {
      \shrodi_print_contents:nn ####1
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shrodi_print_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \textbf{ #1 }: ~ #2 \par \medskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definegroup{grp1}{
  {key 00}{val \emph{00}},
  {key 01}{val 01}
}
\definegroup{grp2}{
  {key 10}{val 10},
  {key 11}{val 11},
  {key 12}{val 12}
}
\definegroup{grp3}{
  {key 20}{val 20}
}

\begin{document}

\processgroups

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should I delete my answer? My Option 2 is essentially the same. I found it in `pgfmanual` but you posted this while I was editing my answer.

Comment: @cfr Your option 1 is not that bad, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

You could store the information indirectly. For example, along with the key and value, you could add a third element to signal a format directive. Your code would then test that and format the value of e.g. `\val` appropriately.

Note that the following example works by adding the text formatting command **without** the leading backslash e.g. `emph` *not* `\emph`. The command is then reconstructed using `\csname ... \endcsname`. Note that I have no idea if this is a good idea or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{grpcnt}
\def\groups{grp1, grp2, grp3}
\def\keyvals{{ {"key 00/val 00/emph, key 01/val 01"}, {"key 10/val 10, key 11/val 11, key 12/val 12"}, {"key 20/val 20"} }}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{grpcnt}{0}
\foreach \grp in \groups {
    \section*{\grp}
    \pgfmathparse{\keyvals[\thegrpcnt]}
    \foreach \key/\val/\form in \pgfmathresult
    {
      \edef\tempa{}%
      \edef\tempb{\form}%
        \textbf{\key}: \ifx\tempa\tempb\val\else\expandafter\csname\form\endcsname{\val}\fi \\[1ex]
    }
    \addtocounter{grpcnt}{1}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Styled <code>\val</code>]

## Option 2

Just use the method mentioned in the documentation for `pgf` and protect the commands with `\noepand`. (See e.g. page 529 of the manual.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{grpcnt}
\def\groups{grp1, grp2, grp3}
\def\keyvals{{ {"key 00/val \noexpand\emph{00}, key 01/val 01"}, {"key 10/val 10, key 11/val 11, key 12/val 12"}, {"key 20/val 20"} }}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{grpcnt}{0}
\foreach \grp in \groups {
    \section*{\grp}
    \pgfmathparse{\keyvals[\thegrpcnt]}
    \foreach \key/\val in \pgfmathresult
    {
        \textbf{\key}: \val \\[1ex]
    }
    \addtocounter{grpcnt}{1}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Partially styled <code>\val</code> with <code>\noexpand</code>]

Comment: Well thought! However I need to be able to format only some words and not others, like only the "00" in my example... In my real-life case, the values are whole sentences and sometimes I would need to use italics or bold on some words, so I need to be able to mark a word independently.